# Angular directive to create canvas and download as image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using Angular 1.5.6 and I want to create a HTML canvas (that's NOT in the DOM) and download as an image. I did it in pure javascript, you can see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uj2vteqv/1/). The Fiddle code is:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/**
 * Demonstrates how to download a canvas an image with a single
 * direct click on a link.
 */
function doCanvas() {
    /* draw something */
    ctx.fillStyle = '#f90';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '20px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText('some text', 10, canvas.height / 2 - 15);
}

/**
 * This is the function that will take care of image extracting and
 * setting proper filename for the download.
 * IMPORTANT: Call it from within a onclick event.
*/
function downloadCanvas(link) {
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.download = 'test.png';
}

/** 
 * The event handler for the link's onclick event. We give THIS as a
 * parameter (=the link element)
*/
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this);
}, false);

/**
 * Draw something to canvas
 */
doCanvas();
```

However, I'm struggling to get it working in an Angular directive. My directive is:

```
angular.module('myApp.analyse')
        .directive('export', exportGates);

function exportGates($location) {

    function createCanvas(gates) {

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = 600;
            canvas.height = 600;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.fillStyle = '#f90';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
            ctx.font = '20px sans-serif';
            ctx.fillText('some text', 10, canvas.height / 2 - 15);

            return canvas;
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'analyse/directives/export.tpl.html',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('click', function () {

                var canvas = createCanvas(scope.gates);

                element.href = canvas.toDataURL();
                element.download = 'export.png';                        

            });
        }
    }
}
```

The issue appears to be that in my first example, the callback to addEventListener is passed 'this', which is the link I need to attach the href and download attributes to automatically download on the click. I thought 'element' in my directive link method was what I needed to attach the href and download attributes to, but obviously not. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element actually is an instance of `jQLite` element which is like a jQuery element, from which you could try to `find` your link inside it and execute the process to download your canvas.

However, I have a better solution that doesn't require an existing link, but rather create your own link and dispatch a click on it without even having to add it to the DOM.

The following snippet implements this solution.

```
function saveCanvasAs(canvas, fileName) {
    // get image data and transform mime type to application/octet-stream
    var canvasDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL()
            .replace(/^data:image\/[^;]*/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
    var link = document.createElement('a'); // create an anchor tag

    // set parameters for downloading
    link.setAttribute('href', canvasDataUrl);
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('download', fileName);

    // compat mode for dispatching click on your anchor
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var evtObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evtObj.initEvent('click', true, true);
        link.dispatchEvent(evtObj);
    } else if (link.click) {
        link.click();
    }
}
```

Finally, you can call it inside your directive like so:

```
...
var canvas = createCanvas(scope.gates);
saveCanvasAs(canvas, 'export.png');
...
```